# How to set System properties (awt.toolkit) in Java 1.7 Or how to set java runtime parameters in Java 1.7?

Tags: java, properties, toolkit

My application needs to set my customToolkit(myapp.MyToolKit) replacing the default Java toolkit (sun.awt.windows.WToolkit).

**Java 1.6**
Till Java 1.6 we had modified the Deployment.properties file and it worked. We could see the changes in Java control panel and the custom toolkit used to get picked up. also the classpath what we set used to work.

**\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties\Deployment.properties shows...**

```
awt.toolkit = myapp.MyToolKit
javaplugin.vm.options = -Djava.class.path=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre6\classes;C:\Users\Administrator\tre\mytool\hletkdevglobalorgcom\LoadJar.jar;;  -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre6\lib\deploy.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre6\lib\plugin.jar -Xmx96m -Djavaplugin.maxHeapSize=96m -Xverify:remote -Djavaplugin.version=1.6.0_33 -Djavaplugin.nodotversion=160_33 -Dbrowser=sun.plugin -DtrustProxy=true -Dapplication.home=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre6 -classpath=C:\Users\Administrator\tre\mytool\hletkdevglobalorgcom\LoadJar.jar;; -Dawt.toolkit=myapp.MyToolKit
```

**Control Panel - Runtime Parameters show...**

-classpath=C:\Users\Administrator\tre\mytool\hletkdevglobalorgcom\LoadJar.jar;; -Dawt.toolkit=myapp.MyToolKit

**Java 1.7.0_75**
In 1.7 when we modify the deployment.properties file, changes are shown in Java control panel, runtime parameter settings but my custom toolkit is not being picked up. And also the classpath setting is not being used.

Tried the following...

1. System.setProperty("awt.Toolkit","myapp.MyToolKit"); 
       System.getProperty("awt.Toolkit") returns myapp.MyToolKit. But Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit() returns default sun Toolkit.
       This is working in a standalone java program. But it doesnot work in a Applet. 
       Our application starts as a jnlp file.. launching applet.
2. JAVA_OPTS system variable
3. JAVA_TOOL_OPTS system variable

Please let me know
1. If you know any way to set System properties like awt.toolkit in Java 1.7 or later?
2. Why the settings done in java control panel are not being recognized. -Dawt.toolkit or -classpath etc.

Comment: Consider adding `Java` tag.

Answer (score 1):

For applets you can specify vm arguments using the <param/> tag.

more information can be found on the oracle website: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html

Example:

> <jnlp>
>   ...
>   <applet-desc 
>    ...your applet arguments...
>   >
>   <param name="java-vm-args" value="#your arguments as passed in to the deployment.properties in former versions#" />
>   </applet-desc>
>   </jnlp>